# Accessing a MySQL running on docker running on ubuntu server

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I have a mysql database running in a docker container which in itself runs on an ubuntu server. My wish is now to be able to, from an external computer on the same network, access the mysql database.

As far as I've understood docker is running its own environment within the ubuntu server. Within this docker environment the MySQL database is running. So accessing the MySQL database from the localhost (the server) with mysql goes fine.

I'm now trying to access the MySQL from the external computer with MySQL, Toad(https://www.quest.com/toad/) and python.

And I get the following errors.

From MySQL: ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '130.235.168.214;' (0)

From Toad: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.

From Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in **in
it**
    super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at '
reading initial communication packet', system error: 0")

So I'm now wondering if I need to forward MySQLs "standard port" 3306 to a port which I then can use to access the MySQL inside docker inside the server?
How do I go from here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running this mysql docker container on a Linux machine then

1. You need to expose port of mysql docker container (Refer: https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-port-expose/)

If you are running this container inside a virtual machine then

2. You also need to forward the virtual machine port. (Refer https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/)